# Lots of ping failure - manual ARP seems to fix it

Tags: centos, ping

Weird issue I'm having.

I have a monitoring system (similar to nagios) running on centos 6

I monitor many nodes, most of the switches we monitor have been given a different subnet to free up some addresses for DHCP hosts.

The switches are on 172.16.200.0/24
Monitoring server is 172.16.200.30/24
My IP is 172.16.1.250/16 (ubuntu)

The nodes on the 172.16.200.0/24 subnet are constantly up and down.
However, when I SSH to the monitoring system I can temporarily fix this issue like this:

```
ping 172.16.200.35
PING FAIL
arping 172.16.200.35
OK
ping 172.16.200.35
PING SUCCESS
```

These switches were fine when they were on 172.16.1.0/24 subnet, but now they don't work well...any ideas on where to start?

Also, another machine in my own office running windows 10 can access everything flawlessly, it is 172.16.1.91/16

Sorry for not posting the routing tables.

My PC:

```
$ ip -4 a show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.1.250/16 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 172.16.1.254 dev eth0 onlink 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.250
```

Monitoring System:

```
# ip -4 a show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.1.30/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet 172.16.3.30/24 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global eth0:0
    inet 172.16.200.30/24 brd 172.16.200.255 scope global eth0

# ip r
172.16.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.3.30 
172.16.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.30 
172.16.200.0/24 dev eth0  scope link 
172.16.200.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.200.30 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
default via 172.16.1.254 dev eth0
```

Comment: Have you checked the routing tables prior to and after the arping? 'ip neigh show'. How do you route from your workstation to the switch subnet?  Lastly any VLAN usage?

Comment: Routing tables for monitoring system is good, for my PC is good too.
On my PC:
Have "kind of" tried ip neigh show before after.
Sometimes the ARP resolves an IP to the wrong HW ADDR, like the HW ADDR of the switch.
I used this to just do a scan:
for i in `seq 30 60` ; do arping -c 1 172.16.200.$i | grep reply |grep -v "64:00:F1:C9:EA:54" ; done
64:00:F1:C9:EA:54 comes up for every IP it cannot reach.

Comment: No VLANs.
No special routing.
Do you want me to print the routing table?

Comment: You're running one host on a /16 and then "moving things onto different /24's (within that /16) to free up DHCP addresses?" Here's a bet that you could easily do what you need in a /22 to /18 without adding any of the complications you have now (but you'll have to change some addresses, or you could just run it all in the /16, but almost nobody I know runs anything big enough to need that.)

Comment: It's got to be a 16 subnet because we're a car dealership group, and we've subnetted out each dealership. I just arbitrarily chose 172.16.200 because I plan to move all hypervisors, VMs, switches and utilites to it's own subnet.
I'm not that deep into the plan that I can't make it something below 172.16.100, but that's a subnet I cannot change.
Perhaps it doesn't need to be quite as large as 16, but not far off it.
I made an error with the switches, they are 172.16.200.0/16, not 172.16.200.0/24 - I am very sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**Layer 2 or Layer 3 issue**

I mis-'spoke' a bit in my comment - I mean to ask for the contents of the arp table on the host that was having trouble pinging the switches / server both BEFORE and AFTER the arpping.  In part I was curious if the 'before' arp entry was a non-response (FAILED) or if the MAC address changed due to the arping.

To get this info, you can use the command:

```
 ip neigh show
```

or the deprecated
     arp -a

You can pass the `ip` command a specific interface (phy) to limit the output to that NIC.

For this type of problem it's most likely that you are having a layer 2 or 3 issue. This is a huge over-simplification, but in very loose terms you can think of these two layers in these ways:

- Layer 2 (data link layer) is where the Address Resolution Protocol facilitates mapping IP addresses to physical MAC addresses
- Layer 3 (aka network layer) is where IP based routing takes place.

A physical layer issue; layer 1; would involve cabling, NIC HW, etc., and typically wouldn't repair itself so repeatably with an arping, and there is no evidence it's a higher layer issue (TCP/UDP or application level).

Since you are now saying the MAC address for a failed ping changes from one 'real' MAC address to another, it is very possible that you have duplicate IP addresses (or exceedingly unlikely for 'purchased' equipment) duplicate MACs.

I think the best next step is to take an inventory of the IP and MAC addresses being used on the LAN

**Generate a network map**

Using [nmap](https://nmap.org/) ([zenmap, the GUI frontend](https://nmap.org/book/zenmap.html) to it adds some visuals to the results as well - I recommend it for this), run the following command to get a topology of the 'problem' subnet:

```
 sudo nmap -sn -PR 172.16.200.0/24
```

If you are using zenmap, just paste that command into the 'command' window in the GUI, and hit 'scan'.

In case you are totally unfamiliar with nmap, here's what the output looks like from this scan (on my boring home network), 192.168.1.1/24

> ```
> Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-27 22:25 EST
> Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
> Host is up (0.00021s latency).
> MAC Address: C4:04:XX:XX:XX:XX (Netgear)
> Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.40
> Host is up (0.0014s latency).
> MAC Address: 28:92:XX:XX:XX:XX (Hewlett Packard)
> ...
> (...skipping to bottom...)  
> ...
> Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (19 hosts up) scanned in 3.72 seconds
> ```

It's self explanatory - the output will only contain the responding hosts and their MAC and IP addresses. It is possible you will get only one or the other from a host.

In zenmap you can get a visual topology by hitting the 'topology' tab. By default it's usually all clumped together, so you'll probably have to hit the 'controls' button and tweak the layout before its usable. Regardless of the data source (visual vs. text), pull it all together and review it for:

1. Any duplicate IP addresses or MAC addresses
2. Any missing or unexpected hosts
3. Any errors noted by nmap

If nothing jumps out at you with the /24 scan, widen it up to cover additional networks (/16 will take significantly longer).

If you need to do a huge subnet (/8) then pings become time prohibitive (waiting for ~16M pings to time out..), and you can drop the -sn argument from nmap and just use the -PR (which is arping).

If you can't find anything helpful in the data, please update your question with as much of it as you are comfortable posting (potentially to a 3rd party site like pastebin to leave your question readable).

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind effort you have put into writing this.
I have used nmap before it's a wonderful tool even when you only know a fraction of it's use!
I didn't know about zenmap - that will be excellent!
I managed to repair the issue on the monitoring PC by re-writing my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* files from scratch.
On my PC it still doesn't work properly because I'm still using a /16 subnet, whereas the monitoring system has three IPs all on /24 subnets, one on the 200 subnet.
I believe I may be able to repair my PC by checking the switches are on /16 subnet.